# Usage of "no other"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, negation

I have a question regarding usage of "**no other**". I know **no** can be used with "singular countable nouns" as well as "plural countable nouns" but I don't know if I can use "no other" in the same way as **no**.

Here are the examples:

1- This is the only branch of Traders & engineers Pvt Ltd. We have **no other branch(es)** than this.

2- Peter: Subha, The pen you gave me has broken. Do you have any other pen? Me: No, I have **no other** **pen(s)**.

My main question is, can I use singular nouns after "no other"? And would you choose "plural nouns" or "singular nouns" in the above examples?

Can anyone who has good knowledge in english answer my question please?

Answer (score 4):

It's interesting in this context because normally using plural or singular nouns depends on whether you use "is/are." (*i.e*. "There are no other pens") But to say "I have no other" doesn't require plural or singular.

"I have no other choice."

"I have no other options."

Both are fine.